# html keygen alternative, generating key pair in browser

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, ssl, encryption

I need an alternative for the html tag keygen for authentication via client certificates. I have only found outdated js libs so far like jcryption or  pidCrypt that are no longer maintained. Is there a way to generate rsa key pairs on the client and to store the private key in the browsers key store across at least chrome, safari and firefox.

I know node.js does something like that, but I have a pretty big application that's already written in php with codeigniter and I don't think that you can implement only some of the encryption libs. Also as far as I can tell node.js has a c/c++ backend that uses openssl on the server, so it's not generated on the client.

I'm new to SSL and client certificates so I'd appreciate any advice on how to implement client certificates.

So far I've done the following:

1. Use keygen tag (still works in firefox) to generate key pair. Private key gets stored in browser.
2. Use public key to generate cert with openssl on the server.
3. Implement cert in users browser via application/x-509-server-cert MIME type. (I've read, that this also won't be supported much longer)

Is there a way to do this so the private key doesn't leave the clients computer or should I just generate everything on the server, then encrypt it with a password and send a p12 file to the user and delete everything on the server afterwards?

Please help!

Comment: If you're talking about generating client certificates in JavaScript and storing them in the browser, then I'm wondering why you're bringing server technologies into it. Particularly, *I know node.js does something like that* - what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @ArtjomB. My bad. All I wanted to say in that paragraph is that node.js is not an option, so people wouldnt point me to it, I guess

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same. I can generate a p12 on the server, but the browser will only download it, not open the install dialog. It seems it will only use the install dialog if you send only the signed cert, not a PK12, and only if the private key already exists on the client. Which is problematic with the deprecation of certain keygen/certificate features.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I was looking for similar library and found a popular library for the same i.e. node-forge. This library's weekly downloads is above 4 million and has been there for past 7 years. In addition, it has been regularly updated, as can be checked by their version releases.

- RSA Keypair generation sample using node-forge:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge#rsa
- node-forge Git Project URL: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

Answer (score 0):

In case you already have a `<keygen>`-based setup and want to keep using it, I created a project which attempts to implement a JavaScript polyfill for `<keygen>`:

https://github.com/CyberShadow/keygen.js